# let my function use user object implicitly

Tags: android

Imagin I have these blocks, I want to eliminate the passing of userLogObject each time,
is there any way in android or kotlin that do this, I think there is some logic that can define in the application class

```
fun <T> call(logObject: LogObject , block: () -> T) {
        return try {
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        logObject.log
    }
    }

ex:
call(userLogObject()){

}
call(userLogObject()){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `extension` function instead. Like:

```
 fun <T> LogObject.call( block: () -> T){
    return try {
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        this.log
    }
}
```